# recurring payment with paypal advanced NOT paypal pro

Tags: paypal

I am trying to make recurring payment work with PAYPAL ADVANCED
My script works in case of SALE transactions but there are issues when i try to create recurring profile.

**ISSUES**

1. When i am posting my request with `CREATESECURETOKEN` set to `Y`. It returns `Invalid transaction type: Invalid Transaction Type for secure token creation request`
   Here is the string. Note i have changed user and pass here

   PARTNER[6]=PayPal&VENDOR[10]=#####&USER[11]=#####&PWD[9]=#####&CREATESECURETOKEN[1]=Y&TRXTYPE[1]=R&RECURRING[1]=Y&TENDER[1]=C&ACTION[1]=A&PROFILENAME[6]=Gautam&ACCT[16]=4012888888881881&EXPDATE[4]=1214&AMT[5]=10.00&START[8]=06132013&PAYPERIOD[4]=MONT&TERM[1]=0&OPTIONALTRX[1]=S&OPTIONALTRXAMT[4]=2.00&EMAIL[20]=#####&SECURETOKENID[26]=MySecTokenID-51b93e0830f70&RETURNURL[51]=http://localhost:8080/php/test/payflow/advanced.php&CANCELURL[51]=http://localhost:8080/php/test/payflow/advanced.php&ERRORURL[51]=http://localhost:8080/php/test/payflow/advanced.php&BILLTOFIRSTNAME[4]=John&BILLTOLASTNAME[3]=Doe&BILLTOSTREET[12]=123 Main St.&BILLTOCITY[8]=San Jose&BILLTOSTATE[2]=CA&BILLTOZIP[5]=95101&BILLTOCOUNTRY[2]=US&SHIPTOFIRSTNAME[4]=Jane&SHIPTOLASTNAME[5]=Smith&SHIPTOSTREET[13]=1234 Park Ave&SHIPTOCITY[8]=San Jose&SHIPTOSTATE[2]=CA&SHIPTOZIP[5]=95101&SHIPTOCOUNTRY[2]=US
2. if i set `CREATESECURETOKEN` to `N` i receive `Invalid merchant information: 10002-You do not have permissions to make this API call`

I searched for documentation on recurring payment with paypal advanced but every where i found details about payflow pro. With no information about recurring payment with paypal advanced its not easy to make things work.
Any idea about what is wrong with my post data?.

I posted my query on paypal.com/mts a week back but have no reply. 
NOTE: I have subscribed to paypal advanced and paypal recurring payment.
With paypal advanced the transactions are completed on the client website itself and user is never taken to paypal site. Yes it uses iframe for the purpose.
It works for SALE type transaction but not in case of recurring payment.

Answer (score 0):

Payments Pro and Advanced don't support the Recurring Payment API calls. You would be using the Recurring Billing API calls through Payflow. The new Advanced and Pro accounts use Payflow Pro or Link.

Are you setting a billing type in the Secure Token call?

What is the ticket number you submitted? I'd to look up the account to see if the account is setup to use Recurring Billing and was created correctly.

Also, Advanced accounts shouldn't be using the Recurring Billing API calls. It is possible to create Recurring Billing profiles with an Advanced account but they have to be done through the PayPal Manager site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes i am using payflow to make a call. I am setting "TRXTYPE=R" not sure what you meant by "billing type".
My ticket number is 130613-000240

Comment: I'll take a look at the ticket and respond to it.

Comment: Thanks for replying to my paypal ticket.I am having hard time to explain this to my client as he says paypal representatives (sales) told him that payment advance works with recurring payment.

Comment: If you use Recurring Payments through PayPal Express Checkout API calls it would work but here you're using Payflow calls with an Advanced account. It's confusing.

Comment: Yes i had implemented recurring payment with express checkout but my client wanted the entire payment to be processed on his website where as express checkout takes user to paypal page. I know this can be done using payments pro but it was expensive solution for client as paypal charges around $30/month for this service. some one from paypal team told my client that payments advanced works with recurring payment and he signed up with payments advanced. While integrating payments advanced i did realize that it processed regular payments but not recurring payments.

Comment: But i was not confident and wanted to make sure before advising my client about the issue with payments advanced. Thanks for clearing my doubts.

Comment: Payments Pro DOES support Recurring Payment API Calls...I'm using it right now...